# Html.EditorFor() -- editor template in portable area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

I am trying to use a partial view editor template in my application using the Html.EditorFor method in my view.  If the editor template is directly in the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates directory of my application, it works great.  If the editor template in the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates directory of the portable area I am using in my application (which is my intent in using this so I can use the same template in more than just this application), it is not being found.  Is there a way I can make it locate the view in the portable area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the location of the template:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo, "~/somepath/to/template.ascx") %>
```

Comment: thanks very much for the answer.  i've been banging my head against this trying to get it to work, and i just can't seem to make it happen.  my template ascx file is set as embedded resource and i'm using this: <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo, "~/PortableAreaName/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/template.ascx") %>.  that's the right path, right?  this is supposed to work, right?  has anyone ever actually done this and seen it work?

Comment: what i was trying to do before that wasn't working just now seems to magically work.  not sure i understand it, but will just accept this answer.