# Html.EditorFor not loading custom template paths

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In my program I have put,

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.EducationData
                      , "~/Views/HTML/Shared/EditorTemplates/Foo/CustomTemplate.ascx")%>
```

but it doesn't load the editor templates from the path I've given. I've seen in some of the examples,[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055805/html-editorfor-editor-template-in-portable-area) where they have given custom paths for the templates. Can anyone suggest something? or does MVC2 supports custom paths for editor templates? or Is there a way to customize the web.config or some configurations,so I could change the default template locations???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have too many folders. There is a specific convention you should follow when using EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates. Try putting your templates in this folder and it should work:

```
"~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CustomTemplate.ascx"
```

**Update:**

Not all of your editortemplates need to go into the Shared folder. You can put controller-specific templates into controller-specific folders too:

```
"~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/CustomTemplate.ascx"
```

Comment: That does work. But isn't there any way to give a custom path?

Comment: You may be able to, but I believe it would require a custom view engine. When it comes to EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates, I find its best to just follow the conventional folder structure.